# What is temporarily using my sbs 2003 disk space

Tags: disk-space

We have a drive space alert that is happening twice every day at about 6:40am and 12:40pm.  I don't want to alter the alert but I do want to find where the drive space is going.  I have carefully examined the scheduled tasks and none of them are using the space.  I have tried Jdiskreport but this hasn't help me find the temporary filename/location either.  Using windows explorer to watch the C drive space I have seen the the drive space drops by about 1gb in the course of 30 minutes and then is released .... looks like some scheduled event is using a 1gb temporary file but I can't find who or where.

My question is HOW can I find what file(s) are being created and then deleted which are temporarily using this 1gb space? Is there some way to see what ALL the files are that are open at any time on sbs 2003?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [TreeSize Free](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/) to track the used space. Start TreeSize Free when your disk-space is getting low again. In addition, you could check application and systemlog for events that occured while your disk-space is getting low.